# Does WebGPU Have Significant Feature/Functionality Gaps As Compared to Vulkan/DirectX12/Metal?

Tags: vulkan, directx12, metal, api

A friend and I are considering using webgpu native (more specifically [C++ bindings](https://github.com/eliemichel/WebGPU-Cpp)) for a project. We were wondering, since WebGPU likely runs on top of Vulkan XOR DirectX12 XOR Metal at any given time, and others have called it a "union" (interpreting the word in the set-theoretic sense) of the three if there were significant feature/functionality gaps with WebGPU as compared with these APIs? In other words, if Vulkan has a feature DirectX 12 does not or vise-versa, does WebGPU exclude it?
What I am asking is: *are there significant features (or functionality differences) these other APIs have, that WebGPU does not, or do they have feature parity?*

NOTE: There is not webgpu tag yet so I did not put it here

Comment: Full disclosure I also posted a thread on wgpu's github https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/discussions/3804 but I left this up for a more breadth of knowlege